# 1997 Plymouth Voyager (U.S.) Ignition Cylinder R&R

Tags: ignition

Attempting to replace the ignition key cylinder.  Attached are the instructions and photo's of the Voyager we're trying to replace the cylinder.   I just don't see any **access** to the "cylinder release tab" or the "retaining tab" (same thing.) Do you?

It "looks" like the tab might be accessible from the "TOP" view, but there isn't an access hole, only a detent with no access to the "cylinder release" tab.

-

[image: Cylinder Set]
[image: Instructions]
[image: Top View]
[image: Bottom View]
[image: Drawing]
[image: Key View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perplexing situation solved.

As shown in the photograph with the red circle, the “tamper-proof” lock protector has “tamper-proof” screws - screws without heads or other visible means of support or removal.  I drilled out the visible screw and cut away (with a cut-off saw) the housing hosting the screw closest to the instrument panel.   Once these two scallywags were removed, the “tamper-proof” housing slid right over and off the cylinder exposing the cylinder release (retaining) tab.    Remainder of project accomplished without fanfare.

[image: Scallywag]
[image: Culprits_1]
[image: Culprits_2]
[image: Finished!]

I am now "one with the mini-van" once again.  *Thankfully, the Suburban just keeps on chuggin'!*

Answer (score 1):

I can't get much from the pic but this is what I could figure it out try to remove the cover 1 or 2 in the pic to see if there is the retaining tab 
[image]